# Add url link to email

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to create a custom url and pass it into a HTML email. The email works however right now I have to manually change the url when I push the application live to contain the live url address. Is there a way to do this?

**What I'm trying to do:**

```
Dev enviroment
localhost:3000/profile

Live enviroment
www.address.com/profile
```

--

```
sendEmail: function (subject, userId) {
    check([subject, userId], [String]);

    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    SSR.compileTemplate( 'htmlEmail', Assets.getText( 'sendEmail.html' ) );

    // to find the users info for the logged in users
    // var user = Meteor.user();

    var emailData = {
      url: Meteor.absoluteUrl() + "/profile"
    };

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      html: SSR.render( 'htmlEmail', emailData )
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure `ROOT_URL` variable in your production environment. When you do so, the method `Meteor.absoluteUrl("/profile")` will return the correct URL.